# does rubymine have an auto backup feature?

Tags: rubymine

I just accidentally overwrite a code file I was working on. But I was working on it in rubymine for a few hours. Does Rubymine have a feature where it automatically backs up the files I'm working on?

(I searched but couldn't find it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called Local History. You can access it through the VCS menu.

Comment: doesn't look like that's what I need. I need an autoback up, independent from git.

Comment: Local history is automatic and independent from git.

Comment: @CJohnson local history has nothing to do with git, because it can track history of changes that were not even committed into git, you could just right click any file in the project browser and you'll find a local history menu, you can check the blog post in rubymine's blog http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2012/10/using-local-history-for-code-changes-tracking/